# What's the best way to add new attributes to MarkerOptions in Mapbox [Android]?

Tags: android, mapbox

I am trying to add new attributes to a marker in Mapbox, extending the classes is getting a little messy.

What is the best way to add new attributes to a marker?

Comment: What atributes do you want to add ?

Comment: I have a custom class that i'd like to add.  It contains an enum and strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with `4.1.0` we introduced marker views. These extend the Android View class and allow you to create your own marker adapter. I've created [a good example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/location/AnimatedLocationIconActivity.java) doing this you can find in the demo app. I'll post some of the snippets of code here but it might be easier just looking at the source code on Github.

Adapter:

```
// Custom marker view used for pulsing the background view of marker.
private static class PulseMarkerViewAdapter extends MapboxMap.MarkerViewAdapter<PulseMarkerView> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public PulseMarkerViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context) {
  super(context);
  this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View getView(@NonNull PulseMarkerView marker, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder viewHolder;
  if (convertView == null) {
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pulse_marker, parent, false);
    viewHolder.foregroundImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foreground_imageView);
    viewHolder.backgroundImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.background_imageview);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
  }
  return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
  ImageView foregroundImageView;
  ImageView backgroundImageView;
}
}
```

PulseMarkerView:

```
public class PulseMarkerView extends MarkerView {

public PulseMarkerView(BaseMarkerViewOptions baseMarkerViewOptions) {
    super(baseMarkerViewOptions);
}
}
```

and lastly, PulseMarkerOptions:

```
public class PulseMarkerViewOptions extends BaseMarkerViewOptions<PulseMarkerView, PulseMarkerViewOptions> {

public PulseMarkerViewOptions() {
}

protected PulseMarkerViewOptions(Parcel in) {
position((LatLng) in.readParcelable(LatLng.class.getClassLoader()));
snippet(in.readString());
title(in.readString());
flat(in.readByte() != 0);
anchor(in.readFloat(), in.readFloat());
selected = in.readByte() != 0;
rotation(in.readFloat());
if (in.readByte() != 0) {
  // this means we have an icon
  String iconId = in.readString();
  Bitmap iconBitmap = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
  Icon icon = IconFactory.recreate(iconId, iconBitmap);
  icon(icon);
}
}

@Override
public PulseMarkerViewOptions getThis() {
  return this;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
  return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
out.writeParcelable(getPosition(), flags);
out.writeString(getSnippet());
out.writeString(getTitle());
out.writeByte((byte) (isFlat() ? 1 : 0));
out.writeFloat(getAnchorU());
out.writeFloat(getAnchorV());
out.writeFloat(getInfoWindowAnchorU());
out.writeFloat(getInfoWindowAnchorV());
out.writeByte((byte) (selected ? 1 : 0));
out.writeFloat(getRotation());
Icon icon = getIcon();
out.writeByte((byte) (icon != null ? 1 : 0));
if (icon != null) {
  out.writeString(getIcon().getId());
  out.writeParcelable(getIcon().getBitmap(), flags);
}
}

@Override
public PulseMarkerView getMarker() {
  return new PulseMarkerView(this);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<PulseMarkerViewOptions> CREATOR =
new Parcelable.Creator<PulseMarkerViewOptions>() {
  public PulseMarkerViewOptions createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    return new PulseMarkerViewOptions(in);
  }

  public PulseMarkerViewOptions[] newArray(int size) {
    return new PulseMarkerViewOptions[size];
  }
};
}
```

Essentially this exposes the markerViews background so that we can pulse (animate) it but you can setup your own attributes. More examples of this being done can be found in the [testapp](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp). Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Alright, this is a nice solution, the problem is performance. This is very horrible. My app can have 100+ pins shown at a given time. Currently on single city, it shows 100 pins. It is very slow. I was able to implement this using just MarkerOption. But I lack the capability to add some metadta which is very important in my app (which I can do elegantly using this one). I wanted to do the same thing with MarkerOptions. Any idea if this is possible in MarkerOptions as well?

Comment: If you'd like to store metadata with the MarkerOption, you should be able to either extend the object and add your own method for storing, or you can use a [Map<>](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: Yep, thanks! I followed the same step for MarkerOption. It is faster than anything else. MarkerViewOptions is a no-go in our project.

Comment: please document this on your official docs, I always have to come back here just to know how to extend MarkerViews.