# How to extend MarkerOption?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am having a bad time with MarkerViewOption. It is very slow when I reach too many custom marker in the view. I have current implementation using MarkerOption and it is super fast. I going to somehow need to extend MarkerOption.

I found tobruns comment on one the issues [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3756). It is similar to what cammace mentioned on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275733/whats-the-best-way-to-add-new-attributes-to-markeroptions-in-mapbox-android).

My question is, is there going to be a problem in the future using tobrun's approach? I haven't heard from that issue since then and I don't know if this is totally supported.